# Operator does not exist date=integer when filtering for dates in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a large data set on dbeaver (postgreSQL), and I am trying to filter for the following:

```
select * from raw_data_file where data_file_group_id  = 2592 and dl_date = 2022-06-15
```

However, I am getting an error for the `dl_date` part of the filter- any suggestions?

```
SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: operator does not exist: date = integer¶  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.¶  Position: 74
```

Comment: `and dl_date = '2022-06-15'`

Comment: Without quotes, the database will do some math: 2022 minus 6 minus 15 and the result will be an integer value.

Comment: Yes, this was exactly the sort of thing the change in casting in version 8.3 was meant to catch. For the reasons why see [8.3 Release Notes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/release-8-3.html) *E.24.2.1. General Non-character data types are no longer automatically cast to TEXT (Peter, Tom)*.

Answer (score 0):

Stu's comment is correct.  Use quotes, single quotes, otherwise the subexpression looks like a couple of subtractions.